# How can I reinstall Windows XP mode?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp-mode

My Windows XP VM is full of stuff I was testing and don't want on it. I figure that I would just reinstall it.

Can I just download the same files from the Microsoft website and it will overwrite everything? Or do I need to uninstall then reinstall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply uninstall it and then reinstall. ([*Source*](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/fi-FI/w7itprovirt/thread/2fdf6c91-2267-435e-9e70-b5e938d7deb4))

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling is one of the quickest ways. This time I would suggest making a copy of the Windows XP `.vhd` file in the XP mode folder (shortcut in start menu). When something blows up, just copy the good vhd file back in and delete the old one.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest uninstall/reinstall. Microsoft doesn't provide you with any like that. Depending on the software tested, some hardware-specific items may have been altered. Regardless of whether or not MS did in fact have such files, you would be out of luck for repairing absolutely every one of them.

This is disregarding the registry, and other components.